# Show that the matrix represents a series of rotation and reflection

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem: Show that the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
represents a rotation $R_\theta$ about a line $l$ through the origin followed by a reflection $H_l$ about the plane through the origin that is perpendicular to the line $l$. You have to find the standard matrices of $R_\theta$ and  $H_l$.

My Attempt: I calculated the determinant of A which was -1. I know that A is a orthogonal matrix, and since it has a determinant of -1, it involves reflection. However, I can't think of a way to find the line $l$.

Hints please?

Comment: Very much similar to a permutation matrix

Comment: @ user675453 I'm actually not familiar with the concept. Are you talking about the P matrix in PLU decomposition? Also, if it is though, can you walk me through it?

Comment: yeah. The Matrix containing only one 1 in each row and column. It exactly like that, with opposite vectors (reflection?). I'm not very good at linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $A$ looks a lot like the rotation matrix
$$
R_{\theta} = \pmatrix{0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}.
$$